# How do you make a variable from a string?

Tags: swift, variables

I want to be able to convert a String into a variable name and then use it to call a variable in another Swift file.

```
//ViewController.swift
var hireTypes = ["school", "council", "national"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  var variableFromString = "\(hireTypes[indexPath.row])Data"

  var data = FullData.variableFromString
  print("The data from selected row is \(data)")
}


//FullData.swift
static var schoolData = [
"name": "School",
"warningMessageOne": "Please check system value",
"warningMessageThree": "May or June",
"warningMessageTwo": "Check hire fits in with morning and afternoon school runs"
]

static var councilData = [
"name": "Council",
"warningMessageOne": "Please check system value",
"warningMessageThree": "Aug or June",
"warningMessageTwo": "Check hire fits in with morning and afternoon school runs"
]

static var nationalData = [
"name": "National",
"warningMessageOne": "Please check system value",
"warningMessageThree": "Aug or June",
"warningMessageTwo": "Check hire fits in with morning and afternoon school runs"
 ]
```

I would have used a array for holding this data however Xcode gives the warning that I need to reduce the complexity of the array.

Comment: Why don't you just put those 3 static arrays into one where each index holds your 3 static var's? The index of the hire types array and the new combined array will be the same for correlated information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better option is to use the string as a key into a dictionary to get the values.

E.g.

```
static var dataDictionary = [
"school" : [
    "name": "School",
    "warningMessageOne": "Please check system value",
    "warningMessageThree": "May or June",
    "warningMessageTwo": "Check hire fits in with morning and afternoon school runs"
 ],
"council" : [
    "name": "Council",
    "warningMessageOne": "Please check system value",
    "warningMessageThree": "Aug or June",
    "warningMessageTwo": "Check hire fits in with morning and afternoon school runs"
 ],
 .....
]
```

Then access the data as

```
var data = FullData.dataDictionary[variableName]
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick messages. @Pradeep K I initially used your method however received a complexity warning. Will try this but in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't do that. Variable names are created and evaluated at compile time.

There are a few workarounds. One of them is passing the index and using a switch expression.

```
//ViewController.swift

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  var data = FullData.data(indexPath.row)
  print("The data from selected row is \(data)")
}

//FullData.swift

static func data(index : Int) -> [String:String] {
  switch index {
  case 0: return FullData.schoolData
  case 1: return FullData.councilData
  case 2: return FullData.nationalData
  default: return [String:String]()
  }
}

static var schoolData = [...]
static var councilData = [...]
static var nationalData = [...]
```

or still easier

```
//ViewController.swift

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  var data = FullData.data[indexPath.row]
  print("The data from selected row is \(data)")
}

//FullData.swift

static var data : [[String:String]] {
   return [FullData.schoolData, FullData.councilData, FullData.nationalData]
}

static var schoolData = [...]
static var councilData = [...]
static var nationalData = [...]
```